# How to get rid of dependency errors loading jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

Just downloaded jenkins.war and did a java -jar jenkins.war (on windows 8.1)

going to http://127.0.0.1:8080/manage, i see:

There are dependency errors loading some plugins:

```
Email Extension Plugin v2.47
    JUnit Plugin v1.2-beta-4 is older than required. To fix, install v1.2 or later.
GitHub plugin v1.20.0
    Jenkins Git plugin v2.4.0 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
Jenkins Git plugin v2.5.3
    Matrix Project Plugin v1.4.1 is older than required. To fix, install v1.6 or later.
    Jenkins Mailer Plugin v1.11 is older than required. To fix, install v1.16 or later.
Pipeline v2.2
    Pipeline: Basic Steps v2.0 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
Jenkins Workspace Cleanup Plugin v0.30
    Matrix Project Plugin v1.4.1 is older than required. To fix, install v1.7.1 or later.
GitHub Branch Source Plugin v1.8.1
    Jenkins Git plugin v2.3 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
Pipeline: Basic Steps v2.1
    Jenkins Mailer Plugin v1.11 is older than required. To fix, install v1.13 or later.
GitHub Organization Folder Plugin v1.4
    GitHub Branch Source Plugin v1.5 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
```

Repeating the java -jar jenkins.war, unpacks the war each tine. Is there a place he lives, so that you can just run him from the command line?

How do I get rid of the plugin errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just load the latest version from [jenkins page](http://mirrors.jenkins-ci.org/war-stable/latest/jenkins.war), and install the recommended plugin by default, I don't see any problem like you, console log example as follows after I open the manage page.

Maybe you can redo it with latest jenkins release.

```
八月 22, 2016 8:31:17 上午 hudson.PluginManager dynamicLoad
INFO: Plugin email-ext:2.47 dynamically installed
八月 22, 2016 8:31:17 上午 hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob run
INFO: Installation successful: Email Extension Plugin
八月 22, 2016 8:31:17 上午 hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob run
INFO: Starting the installation of Mailer Plugin on behalf of admin
八月 22, 2016 8:31:17 上午 hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob _run
INFO: Skipping duplicate install of: Mailer Plugin@1.17
八月 22, 2016 8:31:17 上午 hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob run
INFO: Installation successful: Mailer Plugin
```

Comment: i've done that a few times already. but this time it seems to work better. thanks.

Answer (score 5):

**Upgrading to a new `war` file will not update your plugins**, except for a few "internal" plugins that are closely connected to the Jenkins core.

So, when you're switching from an old Jenkins version to a new one (by using a new `war` file), you'll get the warnings that you see.

To solve this, **updating the plugins in the Jenkins update center** will help.

**If you cannot resolve the dependency errors** on GUI level, then (manually) putting the updated `hpi` plugin files to `$JENKINS_HOME/plugins` (and then restarting) is a last resort.

Comment: Thank you sir! I owe you a beer or two ;) lol. If anyone else encounters this problem, this worked for me: 1) go here https://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/git-client/ and download "permalink to the latest", This will get you get-client.hpi 2) In Jenkins > Plugin Manager > Upload plugin > choose that file > You should get "Success" 3) Restart :)

Comment: For me, I need to remove the old version manually so Jenkins install the hpi (probably something went wrong when it tried to update it automatically).