# jenkins 2 dependency errors loading some plugins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a newly intalled jenkins v 2.36 on ubuntu 14.04 LTS. during the installation process jenkins installed all plugins except pipeline and got stuck on installation. After that i restarted jenkins with 
`service jenkins restart` and was able to create new administrative user, Here is the screen shot of error on jenkins dashboard, the correct button doesnt fix this error.
what should i do to resolve this error ?

[image]

The error is

```
There are dependency errors loading some plugins:
Pipeline: Stage View Plugin v2.4
pipeline-rest-api v2.4 is missing. To fix, install v2.4 or later.
Pipeline v2.4
Pipeline: Stage View Plugin v2.4 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is always good to install the plugin via `"Manage Jenkins -> Plugin Manager"` , so that the plugin will install its dependencies automatically.

But sometimes due to slow internet connection or other reasons, it fails to do automatically. In that case, we need to do it manually under the `Manage Plugins -> Advances Option -> Upload plugin`.

So, in your case, it is failing for the below two dependent plugins:

```
pipeline-rest-api v2.4 is missing. To fix, install v2.4 or later.
```

Please install the pipeline-rest-api plugin. Also, please install other dependent plugins too for safer side.

List of dependent plugins for any Jenkins plugin.:

- https://plugins.jenkins.io/workflow-aggregator
- https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Stage+View+Plugin

Answer (score 3):

Helpful link [jenkins_dependency_error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39070521/how-to-get-rid-of-dependency-errors-loading-jenkins) that helped me solve this issue

Download the plugin from here [latest pipeline](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Stage+View+Plugin).

Go to jenkins dashboard > Manage jenkins> Manage Plugin > [select Advanced Tab]
select upload plugin file (select the option "restart after installation"  )